# How do I change the parameter value after t periods in GAMS?

Tags: parameters, gams-math

If I set a parameter value to 5, but after 3 iterations I want it to become say 10, how do I achieve this?

```
    tstep    Years per Period                                /5/
```

shoule become:

```
    tstep    Years per Period                                /10/
```

for periods >3

Comment: 3 iterations of what? Do you want to solve a model in a loop and change that value after the third solve? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Hey, the model runs for a hundred periods:  set t  /100/

So if t>3, tstep should should change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (the $-condition makes sure, that the value of tstep will be changed after the third solve in the loop):

```
Set t /100/;
Parameter
   tstep    Years per Period                                /5/;

...   
loop(t,
   solve m min z use lp;
*  Change value of tstep after the third solve
   tstep$(ord(t)=3) = 10;
);
```

Comment: Just tried it, I get the following Error Message though:

Error 50: Loop controlling index appears in model equation(s)

loop(t,
 solve co2 maximizing utility using nlp;
 tstep$(ord(t)=3) = 5;
);

Comment: And you do not get this, when not changing the value? On a first look, I actually think this is independent and a different problem. It might help, if you can post a minimal example to reproduce this issue.

Comment: No, then it works. I´m modifying the DICE model (https://sites.google.com/site/williamdnordhaus/dice-rice), and even there in the standard version I get the same error message. Not sure why?

Comment: Just define `tstep` over `t` before the loop. I.e. `parameter tstep(t) /5/; tstep(t)$(ord(t) gt 3) = 10`.